# Can I cycle event calls from a jquery click event?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a row highlight to a table row using jquery.  I would like to have 3 pre-defined colors that get cycled using one click event. For instance if the user clicks the row the first time it's highlighted in yellow, another click changes it to orange, a third click changes it to red.

I'm currently able to do this with only a single color (on/off)

Current code:

```
var row_highlight_color = localStorage.getItem('row_highlight_color');  

if (!row_highlight_color) {
    row_highlight_color = '#f89406';
}

// lets get our custom color definition and append it to the style sheet

$('<style>.row_highlight_css { background-color: '+row_highlight_color+' !important; color: #ffffff;}</style>').appendTo('head');

$('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('td').toggleClass('row_highlight_css');
});
```

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: try to generate random number from 1 to 3 and then pick one colur

Comment: declare the colors in arrays and iterate that one by one on every click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a `data` element to store the current state:

```
$('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var col = $this.data('state');         // get current state

    if (col === undefined) {
        col = 0;                           // pick the colour to use on first click
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('row_highlight_' + col);  // remove previous class
        col = (col + 1) % 3;                        // update state
    }

    $this.addClass('row_highlight_' + col) // add new class
         .data('state', col);              // update state
});
```

NB: this will maintain each row's state independently.

Comment: @user1216398 you're welcome.  BTW, is it really necessary to set the style on all the `<td>` children individually rather than on the `<tr>` itself?

Comment: I'll change it...Thanks agian!

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines perhaps?

```
var myColors = ['#f89406','#6f9406','#f84006'];   // whatever colors you want
var colorIndex = 0;

$('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('td').css("background-color",myColors[colorIndex]);
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % myColors.length;
}
```

Comment: what would happen when colorIndex = 3.?

Comment: @Dineshkani: Just fixed that.

Comment: this will not maintain independent colours for each row

Comment: @Alnitak: True enough. You can use `.data()` as you suggested or you could just maintain an array of indexes instead of a single index.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should not use toogleClass, instead user addClass(), removeClass().
You can check the class, with hasClass()

```
var myElement = $('yourElement');
if(myElement.hasClass('first_class')) {
     myElement.removeClass('first_class').addClass('second_class');
} else if(myElement.hasClass('second_class')) {
     myElement.removeClass('second_class').addClass('third_class');
} else {
     myElement.addClass('first_class');
};
```

You can also use the data-class and do somthing like this:

```
var myElement = $('myElement');
var data = myElement.data('class');
switch(data) {
   case 'first':
      myElement.removeClass('first_class').addClass('second_class').data('class', 'second');
      break;
   case 'second':
      myElement.removeClass('second_class').addClass('third_class').data('class', 'thrid');
      break;
   default:
      myElement.addClass('first_class').data('class', 'first');
}
```

You should add the behaviour for after the third click, like this, it will go back to the first class.
Doc for [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)
Hope it helps